# How do i combine my string which contain multiple delimeters in to single string seperated by comma

Tags: c#, string, split

I want to join my string with comma when multiple delimiters are there.

Like for eg: `abc,pqr lmn,rty qqq`

**Input:**

```
SearchKeyword=abc,pqr lmn,rty qqq.ttt
```

**Output**:

```
 string output=searchKeyword.Join(",",searchKeyword.Split(new Char [] {',' ,null))
```

I want my input to be join by comma in a single string variable **output**.

**Output**: `abc,pqr,lmn,qqq,ttt`

How do I do this??

Comment: It is confusing. Don't you think your input and output are always same. You first split by comma then join by comma.

Comment: but what if my input contain whitespace like you can see in my input there is an white space between pqr and lmn

Comment: Use `space` instead of `null`.

Comment: What is your desired output ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is better way to that.. using this you can replace any spacial character with `,`

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input = "abc,pqr lmn,rty qqq.ttt";

        string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"\W", ",");   

        Console.WriteLine(input);
        Console.WriteLine(output);

    }
}
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/PtOPVA

Answer (score 2):

Below code that converts string with comas, white space and semi colons into a string containing only comas. If necessary just extend the collection in `Split` method.

```
var searchKeyword = "abc,pqr lmn,rty qqq";
var split = searchKeyword.Split(new[] {',', ' ', ';'});
var res = String.Join(",", split);
```

**EDIT**

And a oneliner version:

```
var res = String.Join(",", searchKeyword.Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }));
```

Comment: Sure you can, I just split it so the steps are more transparent.

Comment: one thing i dont understand on stackoverflow regarding upvoting and downvoting of the question

Comment: If you think the answer is useful you upvote. If you thing the answer is clearly incorrect you downvote. If the answer answers your question you check the green checkbox saying that that's the answer.